# inner class access of enclosing class members

Tags: java, class, nested

I will be amazed if anyone can answer this question. I am a beginner struggling immensely with the syntax and logic of nested classes in Java. If you run the following program, 'a' will print instead of 'b'. Why?

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Outer OuterRefVar_a = new Outer('a');

        Outer OuterRefVar_b = new Outer('b');

        OuterRefVar_a.InnerTypeMember = OuterRefVar_a.new Inner();

        OuterRefVar_b.InnerTypeMember = OuterRefVar_a.InnerTypeMember;

        OuterRefVar_b.InnerTypeMember.set_innerChar_to_outerChar();

        System.out.println(OuterRefVar_b.InnerTypeMember.innerChar);
    }
}
class Outer
{
    char outerChar;

    Outer(char outerChar)
    {
        this.outerChar = outerChar;
    }

    class Inner
    {
        char innerChar;

        void set_innerChar_to_outerChar()
        {
            innerChar = outerChar;
        }
    }

    Inner InnerTypeMember;
}
```

Comment: Please explain *why* you would expect it to print `b`. I suggest you look at the data in a debugger at each step. It makes sense to me that it prints `a`, but without knowing what your line of reasoning for it printing `b`, it's hard to know where you're going wrong.

Comment: Please use the Java naming conventions. Method, field and local variable names should be camelCase with no underscores.

Comment: You'd prefer setInnerCharToOuterChar? It looks like a mess to me but if that's what you guys want, fine, I'll do that for now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because while you have set the InnerTypeMember reference of object of A onto B..

```
OuterRefVar_b.InnerTypeMember = OuterRefVar_a.InnerTypeMember;
```

The inner object of A still has a reference to it's original Outer object A and will reference its member variables. Java implements inner classes by giving the object a secret reference to "Outer.this" which doesn't change simply by setting the InnerTypeMember on the other instance.

For example, if you had a InnerTypeMember variable within a completely different class, calling set_innerChar_to_outerChar() would still be expected to find Outer.outerChar on the object for which the inner class was original constructed.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would have never figured this out. Is there a way to access an inner class' reference to its outer object?

Comment: You can simply call Outer.this at any time, but you won't be able to change it. (nor should you. change your code to use object references and not try to hack Outer.this)

Comment: How did you learn this? There do not seem to be any resources online that have this information. Maybe I've just been lazy. Are nested classes just not that important?

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. You're the super bomb.

Comment: slipperyseal, when I try to create a method in Inner that assigns Outer.this a reference to an Outer object, it says...error: cannot assign a value to final variable this

Comment: Yes I updates my reply. You can't change this or Outer. this. If you need to access members from other Outer objects you should use a regular variable reference to it.

Comment: So when you directly reference enclosing class non-static members from an inner class, you're referencing members of the enclosing object that provided the context for instantiating the inner class? This seems important to know but it isn't explained anywhere and you seem to know it.

Comment: The actual JVM specs would define this but they are vey technical. I found this tutorial which mentions the hidden reference. http://www.oursland.net/tutorials/java/innerclasses/